# Excel: How do you add a number that passes the other cell?

Tags: excel, windows

How do you write a number that passes the other cell?

Suppose I have this cells A cell + B cell  = C cell (sum)

A is the new entry, B is the old entry, C is sum (A + B)

See below screenshot:

[image: screensoht]

Now, I want to write a new entry on column A, and the present entry of A cell to automatic passes to B cell. How can I do this?

Comment: You can achieve this by using VBA events. please check https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/worksheet_events.php

Answer (score 1):

quite easy.  Put values in **A1** and **B1**.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",A1+B1)
```

and copy downwards.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","",A1)
```

and copy downwards.

As you enter values in column **A**, the previous **A** value will get copied to **B** and the sum will appear in column **C** as well.

[image]

Comment: yes, but I want to keep the current values on B2. If I write this `=IF(A2="","",A1)` it will delete my entry

Comment: @JustMe  I did not understand your original question.  If my answer has no value to you, then un-check the Green check-mark.  This will encourage someone else to respond.

Comment: your answer is ok, must be update a little bit. I must keep the current values on B, after that your formula must be aplied.

Comment: @JustMe  I will not erase my answer...........perhaps someone else will see my answer and your comments and post a better answer.